# DNS NS Records don't show up in nslookup

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain (with Namecheap). I've added 4 NS records for a subdomain, and pointed them at AWS Route 53. Everything works fine.

When I do an nslookup, regardless of the tool, I don't see the NS records I've added coming back in the response. Is this normal?

l
[image]
[image]

Comment: So your DNS works but you can't use nslookup? Please edit your post to specify your domain name and name servers so we can check them. If you don't do that you won't get much useful help. Domain names and name servers are completely public so sharing them is not a security risk.

Comment: @Tim Sorry. can't share the domain

Comment: It's normal not to see NS records if you don't look for them. What nslookup commands are you using?

Comment: Ok. If you decide to share the domain we can help, until then I'll vote to close because we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: @Tim I'm not asking for tech support. I'm asking for an explanation. edited the question.

Comment: I guess you are running `nslookup` against the top-level domain name when it should be alt.yourdomain.tld since that seems to be your subdomain

Comment: That's not normal. Check that you actually set your nameservers correctly at Namecheap.

Comment: If you are asking for an explanation why `nslookup` doesn't work as you expect, it's because you are using it wrong. See my answer for examples.

Comment: And besides, you should prefer `dig` over `nslookup` and always use the `@` option to specify exactly which nameservers you query otherwie you can't do sane troubleshooting. You need to query first the authoritative (after having checked at parent authoritative ones that the delegation is correct) and only if everything is fine then start to query recursive nameservers. I vote to close the question explicitely because you didn't give the name involved, which does not bring you anything useful (the DNS is public) but hinders all efforts for good replies.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I really don't understand the `close` votes. I'm asking about how DNS works, not for anyone to debug my issue

Comment: How the DNS works in general won't be an on topic question here ... except if you have a specific question on why a specific delegation does not work, for which you need to provide the name. Also giving screenshots (that can disappear at any time, that are difficult to read, impossible to search for in the future, etc.) is not a good idea. You also say "When I do an nslookup, regardless of the tool, I don't see the NS records" without providing any example of your commands or their precise replies. That makes some point to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You could as well disclose the domain name; takes less than a minute of reconnaissance to find it.*

From here, the records seem just fine with both...

- DiG with trace

  ```
   $ dig alt.*********r.com. NS @8.8.8.8 +trace

   ; OMITTED . AND com. LEVELS

   *********r.com.         172800  IN      NS      dns1.registrar-servers.com.
   *********r.com.         172800  IN      NS      dns2.registrar-servers.com.
   ; OMITTED NSEC3 & RRSIG RECORDS
   ;; Received 740 bytes from 2001:503:a83e::2:30#53(a.gtld-servers.net) in 36 ms

   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-1204.awsdns-22.org.
   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-190.awsdns-23.com.
   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-666.awsdns-19.net.
   ;; Received 184 bytes from 2610:a1:1025::200#53(dns2.registrar-servers.com) in 24 ms

   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-1204.awsdns-22.org.
   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-190.awsdns-23.com.
   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
   alt.*********r.com.     300     IN      NS      ns-666.awsdns-19.net.
   ;; Received 184 bytes from 2600:9000:5302:9a00::1#53(ns-666.awsdns-19.net) in 20 ms
  ```
- Nslookup

  ```
   > nslookup -querytype=NS alt.*********r.com 8.8.8.8
   Server:  dns.google
   Address:  8.8.8.8

   Non-authoritative answer:
   alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-1204.awsdns-22.org
   alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-190.awsdns-23.com
   alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk
   alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-666.awsdns-19.net
  ```

From the screenshot it seems **you were querying the records for `ANY *********r.com` instead of its subdomain `alt.*********r.com`. Naturally that won't give you the `NS` records for the subdomain.**

See the difference between

```
>nslookup -querytype=ANY *********r.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
*********r.com
        primary name server = dns1.registrar-servers.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.registrar-servers.com
        serial  = 1593846211
        refresh = 43200 (12 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 3601 (1 hour 1 sec)
*********r.com  nameserver = dns1.registrar-servers.com
*********r.com  nameserver = dns2.registrar-servers.com
*********r.com  MX preference = 1, mail exchanger = aspmx.l.google.com
*********r.com  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx2.googlemail.com
*********r.com  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx3.googlemail.com
*********r.com  MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
*********r.com  MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
*********r.com  text =

        "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
*********r.com  internet address = 198.185.159.144
*********r.com  internet address = 198.49.23.145
*********r.com  internet address = 198.185.159.145
*********r.com  internet address = 198.49.23.144
```

and (although you really SHOULD also be using `-querytype=NS` instead of `ANY`, [RFC 8482](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8482))

```
>nslookup -querytype=ANY alt.*********r.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
alt.*********r.com      internet address = 205.251.219.115
alt.*********r.com      internet address = 205.251.219.98
alt.*********r.com      internet address = 205.251.219.122
alt.*********r.com      internet address = 205.251.219.2
alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-1204.awsdns-22.org
alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-190.awsdns-23.com
alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk
alt.*********r.com      nameserver = ns-666.awsdns-19.net
alt.*********r.com
        primary name server = ns-190.awsdns-23.com
        responsible mail addr = awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 7200 (2 hours)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)
```

Comment: per RFC 8482 doing ANY queries is in fact now deprecated, and it never did have the semantic of "ALL" that people thinks it has. Your answer would be far much better if you replace `ANY` queries by `NS` queries because if the problem is checking if `NS` records are there then the solution is to query for them, irrespective to anything else.

Comment: That's already demonstrated in the first example, so the last part is just comparing the levels, demonstrating the exact outcome of the unsuccessful attempt in the question.

Comment: It remains that any suggestion on using `ANY` should be removed. It never was a good way to troubleshoot (because it is not `ALL`, so the results are absolutely not what people think, you view the content of the resolver cache not really all records that exist on a name), and is now even lesser of a good way.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. Although it wasn't really a suggestion, it's now stated more clearly. However, I want to keep the outputs as is, as in this case they are quite informative & revealing.